# IntelliJ: Generating getters/setters for fields with underscores in the name

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to be smarter about the getters/setters it generates?  In particular, if a field name has underscores in it, can the getter strip them out and convert to CamelCase?

For instance, I would expect the below getter to be getCarneAsada():

```
public class Taco {
  private String carne_asada;

  public String getCarne_asada() {
    return carne_asada;
  }
}
```

I found the `Code Style->Java->Code Generation` area, but none of the options seem appropriate...it's not a prefix or a suffix I want to exclude.  It's inner underscores.

Comment: You could (should?) really just rename your field to `carneAsada`. IntelliJ will automatically rename its getter and setter as well.

Comment: In this case I'm using Gson to deserialize some json to this object, and I'd rather not use the magical FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES

Comment: There is no option to tell IntelliJ IDEA to treat underscore differently for getters/setters generation as it's against the Java naming convention.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there any wish list where one can vote for access to the getter/setter templates for customization? Something like the live templates in my answer?

Comment: @maba, yes, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-28206.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Great! You rock!

Comment: You could just use `@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("carne_asada") private String carneAsada;` and generate the default getters and setters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Live Templates to accomplish this. It will not be accessible from Code Generation but it will still be quite easy to use.

I have created a Main class with the property `carne_asada`:

[image]

Now open up `Live Templates` in the settings and create a new template called `getu` under `other`:

[image]

Press the little link called `Define` at the bottom to define when this template is valid. Then choose `Java | Declaration`:

[image]

Press the button `Edit Variables` to open a window where each of the live template variables can be defined. Now create the following variables:

```
VAR         : suggestFirstVariableName("Object")
TYPE        : typeOfVariable(VAR)
CAP_CAM_VAR : capitalize(underscoresToCamelCase(VAR))
```

The order is quite important so the `VAR` must come first. In my example `CAP_CAM_VAR` stands for Capitalize and CamelCase the `VAR` variable. Set the `Skip if defined` according to the image:

[image]

Now press `OK` and `OK` again to get back to the editor.

Try the new `getu` live template by typing `getu` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the getter generation has finished:

[image]

Now if you had had some more variables with underscores you will get a list to choose from so here is an example:

[image]

And the result is just beautiful:

[image]

You can easily create the same `setu` live template and maybe some `sgetu` that creates them both at the same time.

Hope this helps a little bit!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation!  I was hoping to get it while using the normal "generate getter/setter" function but it sounds like @CrazyCoder doesn't think that's possible.

Comment: @Eric No obviously it's not possible yet. Hopefully JetBrains will open up the templates for the code generation so that it is possible to customize them.

Comment: FYI: For those who have underscored prefixed camel case field names (e.g, `_fooBar`) then you can use `capitalize(underscoresToCamelCase(snakeCase(VAR)))` as the expression for `CAP_CAM_VAR` to create `getFooBar()`

Answer (score 8):

Here are templates for generating getter/setter working under IntelliJ IDEA 2016 and Android Studio 2.2.

Camelized Getter:

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  get##
#end
#set($words = $StringUtil.split($name, "_"))
#set($name = "")
#foreach($word in $words)
#set($name = $name + $StringUtil.capitalize($word))
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

Camelized Setter:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#set($words = $StringUtil.split($name, "_"))
#set($name = "")
#foreach($word in $words)
#set($name = $name + $StringUtil.capitalize($word))
#end
void set$name($field.type $StringUtil.decapitalize($name)) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

If you want fluent getter/setter with above, please refer my gists.

https://gist.github.com/k24/72d0be3d76d4eb987c6d4eb1d8f42db2

Comment: Thanks for this! Code works except for a small error in the Camelized Setter. The last line should be `$field.name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name)` so that the field you are setting matches the param of the function.