# How can I modify the IntelliJ getter and setter code generation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation

In IntelliJ you can generate getter and setter methods for your Java class fields. The problem I have is that by our code conventions private fields need to start with an underscore, for example:

```
private String _name;
```

IntelliJ will generated the following getter and setter methods for this field:

```
public String get_reportName()
{
    return _reportName;
}

public void set_reportName(String _reportName)
{
    this._reportName = _reportName;
}
```

I would like it to rather generate:

```
public String getReportName()
{
    return _reportName;
}

public void setReportName(String reportName)
{
    _reportName = reportName;
}
```

Can I somehow customize the generation code to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: It seems some people _can_ write C in any language...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805049/intellij-generating-getters-setters-for-fields-with-underscores-in-the-name

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open IntelliJ Preferences (Command + , on Mac).

Navigate through:

```
Editor
-- Code Style
---- Java
```

Select the `Code Generation` tab. Under `Name prefix:` put an underscore in the `Field:` text box. Now, it should work for you. (At least in IntelliJ 15 where I tested this).

[image]