# How call live template function in setter template?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805049/intellij-generating-getters-setters-for-fields-with-underscores-in-the-name) about live template. It uses `capitalize` and `underscoresToCamelCase`. How to call these functions from setter tempalate? Simply `$underscoresToCamelCase` does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because you don't have access to the live template context within the velocity template.

Have a look at the velocity context. It's created in the [org.jetbrains.java.generate.GenerationUtil#velocityGenerateCode](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/generate-tostring/src/org/jetbrains/java/generate/GenerationUtil.java) method.

Inside the velocity template you have access to different values within the velocity template like:

```
  vc.put("helper", GenerationHelper.class);
  vc.put("StringUtil", StringUtil.class);
```

There is no value representing something like a live template engine.

Furthermore, live templates act in a dynamic context (node(s) in in the syntax tree) in contrast to generate methods. They generate the source code using a velocity template and a fixed context.